# Rails metaprogramming: singleton_class and associations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to understand metaprogramming in rails, creating validations and associations dynamically on a class.

Let's say I have the following models:

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
end

class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Now let's say my `House` model has a boolean attribute `is_ownable`, and I only want the house to have the `owner` association if `is_ownable==true`.

I thought this would work:

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :create_associations
  after_find :create_associations

  def create_associations
    if self.is_ownable
      self.singleton_class.belongs_to :owner
    end
  end
end
```

Now when I build or find a record of House, the `create_associations` function gets called with no errors, but then when I try to access the `House.first.owner` it throws `ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError`.

Am I misunderstanding something about how AR associations work?

Comment: does `h = House.first; h.owner` do the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

I hate to say it but this is probably a bad idea. Models should have consistent relationships even if they're not utilized on every model. This is not only against the spirit of ActiveRecord or Ruby, but object oriented programming in general. In most cases objects of a particular class are expected to have an identical interface for the sake of consistency and clarity. Adding methods to individual objects is permitted, but there should be exceptional circumstances to justify such a thing.

That's not to say you can't get the effect you want in a more idiomatic way:

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner

  validates :validate_owner_assignment

protected
  def validate_owner_assignment
    if (self.ownable? and !self.owner)
      self.errors.add(:owner, "is required if ownable")
    elsif (!self.ownable? and self.owner)
      self.errors.add(:owner, "cannot be assigned if not ownable")
    end
  end
end
```

Now assigning owner will trigger a save failure of type `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` if the expectations aren't met.

I'd advocate calling your booleans `x` and not `is_x` to reduce verbosity. The vast majority of the time the `is_` part is redundant.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, and I agree, but I'm just doing this as an exercise to understand metaprogramming with rails.  Your approach won't work if for example we change the flag after an object already exists.

Comment: There's probably better examples for metaprogramming. Remember the golden rule of trying to do the simplest thing possible, but no simpler. Sometimes metaprogramming, while sexy, complicates understanding. Sometimes it massively simplifies an otherwise messy solution. You need to know when it's applicable. A good example is how ActiveRecord augments regular Array objects with additional methods when retrieving results from a database or generates methods on the fly to match the current schema. Try and write a class-level method like `has_many` that dynamically modifies a class as a first step.